# How does gaming performance affect the rarity of potions I get?

Tags: agar.io

I often get Common Potions in *agar.io*, sometimes I get Rare Potions, and seldom I get some higher level potion. The rarity of the potion seems to be connected to my gaming performance.
How are they related?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the correlation between game performance and the chance of getting a rare (or higher) potion?

Comment: Not exactly, I want to know the factor it affects the rarity  of potion

Comment: Based on your new title, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Yes, it is I recorrect it